# Web приложение на Java + Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, веб-программирование

Стоит задача написать web приложение на Java (backend) и html+css+javascript(frontend). Java более мение знаю (серверная часть с обращением к главной html страницы написаны и работают) проблема в основном в JS, в данный момент читаю книжку, но там ни слова о том, как подружить js с java. Во условию задания использовать только js и java без фреймворков типа springboot. Подсобите с литературой, что лучше читать, примеры с подобной задачей и подробным пояснением были бы кстати. А то все, на что я наталкивался, это написание java web-приложения с использованием jsp страниц.

Comment: Из вопроса не понятно, какой характер взаимодействия Вам необходимо обеспечить между клиентом и сервером, в целом клиенту не важно на чем написан сервер, он отправляет на сервер запросы - сервер их обрабатывает и возвращает ответ.

Comment: Вы можете написать 2 отдельных приложения, и запустить их по отдельности. И из клиентского использовать серверное. Клиентское можно развернуть, например, через nginx. Другой вариант -- получать JS файлы так же, как получаете сейчас HTML, т.е. обращаясь к серверу на Java за получением файла. Но я такой способ не пробовал.

Comment: Судя по вопросу нужно сделать две простые вещи. Java рожает html страницу, которая отправляется на клиента. В теле страницы прописывается код js. Существует 2 способа получения данных: прописать сразу json в тело страницы при загрузке как переменную js или получить асинхронно через api сервера.  Полагаю проблема в запуске js скрипта. Тут для новичка не очевидно, что для запуска скрипта надо прописать его в `обработчик события document.addEventListener('DOMConentLoaded', function () { здесь код запуска скрипта после загрузки страницы } )`

Answer (score 1):

> как подружить js с java

Им не нужно дружить важно понять как работает приложение

Представить что сайт должен отобразить пост(название, контент и автора)
Ты посылаешь(вбиваешь адрес в поисковике) запрос на свой java сервер и тогда есть варианты:

**Подход 1**: java берет данные из бд о посте(исходя из запроса) и **составляет html** документ вставляя эти данные([jsp](https://metanit.com/java/javaee/3.1.php)) и возвращает клиенту.

**Подход 2**: сервер возвращает html документ, javascript - начинает работу и посылает  запрос серверу на получение данных - сервер их возвращает и javascript уже **составляет html**.([SPA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))

ПС: в обоих случаях сервер возвращает не только html но и js и css и тд. Или же они подтягиваются с сервера потом уже на клиенте отдельными запросами.(для тебя это может быть неявно)

> серверная часть с обращением к главной html страницы написаны и
>   работают

не знаю какая задача, но добавь на эту страницу кнопку, привяжи к ней обработчик нажатия  js. и в нем пошли любой запрос на свой сервер - вот как дружат/взаимодействуют java и js/ сервер и клиент.

Пример:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn"></button>
    <script>
        var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
        btn.onclick = function () {
           // Get получить с сервера порцию данных
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

В любом случае нужно помнить задачи:

сервер(java):управляет ответами на запрос и манипулирует данными на стороне сервера.

клиент(js): взаимодействует с пользователем о**тправляет запросы и обрабатывает ответы сервера**

PS: Когда-то интересовался такими же вопросами и постарался объяснить как для себя - на пальцах. Если есть конкретная задача или недопонимание определенных моментов - уточни.